# Scripting Unity post-processing stack

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, post-processing

I'm trying to imitate a lightning effect in Unity using its post-processing stack's *bloom* effect via script (to modify the intensity), but somehow I'm unable to actually *set* anything via script.

```
PostProcessingProfile postProcProf;
postProcProf.bloom.settings.bloom.intensity = 
Mathf.Lerp(data[i].Strength, data[i + 1].Strength, data[i].TimeToReachNext);
```

This is my code, but it says

> Cannot modify the return value of BloomModel.Settings, because it is not a variable.

I have found no guide on how to **script** post-processing stack, only on how to use it from the editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Unity's guide on modifying post-processing at runtime](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/PostProcessing/wiki/%28v1%29-Runtime-post-processing-modification), you should be modifying a copy of the `settings` value, then overwriting the original with your copy (don't try to change members of `BloomModel.Settings` directly):

```
PostProcessingProfile postProcProf;
var bloom = postProcProf.bloom.settings;
bloom.bloom.intensity = Mathf.Lerp(data[i].Strength, data[i + 1].Strength, data[i].TimeToReachNext);
postProcProf.bloom.settings = bloom;
```

Comment: With one minor edit, in your 3rd line it required `bloom.bloom.intensity`, but it worked perfectly. Seems like I didn't look hard enough, thanks for your help.

Comment: @agiro Glad to help out! Oops, haha, guess that's my punishment for using the same variable name as the member I was accessing!